# Build a compiled delegate corresponding to Enumerable.Cast<T>?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

This is very tricky and I'm stuck at the step calling the generic method (`MethodInfo`) which is returned by another `MethodCallExpression` (by using `MakeGenericMethod`) right inside the expression tree context.

Technically the compiled delegate I want looks like this:

```
Func<IEnumerable, Type, IEnumerable> cast;
```

So instead of using `items.Cast<T>()` I can call my compiled delegate like `cast(items, typeof(T))`.

If using reflection every time calling `cast`, it would be easy but here I would like to build a compiled delegate based on Expression tree. Here is my code:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
    static readonly Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable<object>> _enumerableCast = Enumerable.Cast<object>;
    static readonly Lazy<MethodInfo> _enumerableCastDefLazy = new Lazy<MethodInfo>(() => _enumerableCast.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition());
    static MethodInfo _enumerableCastDef => _enumerableCastDefLazy.Value;
    static Func<Type[], MethodInfo> _makeGenericMethod = _enumerableCastDef.MakeGenericMethod;
    static readonly Lazy<Func<IEnumerable, Type, IEnumerable>> _enumerableCompiledCastLazy =
        new Lazy<Func<IEnumerable, Type, IEnumerable>>(() => {
            var itemsParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable));
            var castTypeParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type));
            var castTypeParams = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Type), castTypeParam);
            var castMethod = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(_enumerableCastDef),_makeGenericMethod.Method, castTypeParams);

            //here we need to call on castMethod (a static method)
            //but the Expression.Call requires a MethodInfo, not an Expression returning MethodInfo
            var cast = Expression.Call(..., itemsParam);//<--------- I'm stuck here

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable, Type, IEnumerable>>(cast, itemsParam, castTypeParam).Compile();
        });
    public static Func<IEnumerable, Type, IEnumerable> EnumerableCompiledCast => _enumerableCompiledCastLazy.Value;

    public static IEnumerable Cast(this IEnumerable items, Type type){
        return EnumerableCompiledCast(items, type);
    }
}
```

So as you can see it's really a dead stuck, never encountered such an issue like this before. I know I can work-around it by invoking the `castMethod` (as a `MethodCallExpression`). That way I need to obtain the `Invoke` method of `MethodInfo` and use `Expression.Call` to call that method on the instance `castMethod`. But wait, if so we still use `Method.Invoke` as we use `Reflection` to write code usually without compiling it? I really believe in some hidden magic of `Expression.Call` which does something different (better and faster) than the `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

Comment: `Type` must be known at the point that you compile the expression. It can't be an input into the compiled delegate. If you write a method which accepts a `Type` and returns a `Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>` (i.e. a delegate which internally calls `.Cast<T>()`, where `T` is the type you pass in), you can make that work

Comment: @canton7 if so it's too easy for me, and doing so does not bring much benefit. We have many unknown `Type` (target cast type) beforehand. So we need to build each delegate for each type and cache them all?

Comment: If this cannot be done, I would like to use reflection directly every time, with as much cache as possible and based on the speed of `MethodInfo.Invoke`, not really bad but of course not better than compiled delegate.

Comment: Yes. The alternative of course is to call Cast using reflection. But, I'm not sure you get much benefit? You can only really do reference conversions

Comment: @canton7 I think the most costly operation involves the `MethodInfo.Invoke` so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Expressions aren't magic, they're just a way of compiling code at runtime. If you can't write C# which does what you want, you won't be able to write an expression which compiles the same thing at runtime

Comment: The most costly thing is getting the MethodInfo. Invoking it is slightly slower than compiling an expression which invokes it (and caching the expression), but it's relatively fast

Comment: @canton7 thanks for your info, but anyway this is a problem of building the expression I want. Even using `reflection` purely is the way to go, this question does still have its own thing to discuss around.

Comment: You can't have IL which calls a generic method, where the generic type parameter is controlled by a Type object at runtime. It doesn't matter what method you use to try and compile to the IL, you simply can't achieve the end result. The value of the generic type parameter either needs to be know at the point that the IL is compiled, or it can be a generic argument.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is completely pointless, and very unlike `Enumerable.Cast`, which actually does something useful.

Let's take a look at the latter's definition:

```
IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source);
```

This takes an untyped `IEnumerable` and returns a typed `IEnumerable<T>` based on the generic argument given to the function. You can then use the elements inside the enumerable with the proper type directly, including value types.

Now let's look at your function definition:

```
IEnumerable Cast(this IEnumerable items, Type type);
```

This takes an untyped enumerable and returns also an untyped enumerable. What it does inside isn't important, because even if it worked as you want, what you get out of this is still an enumerable of plain `object`s, so to use these values you still need to cast these things correctly (and unbox the boxed value types). You achieved nothing at all, you already had such a collection -- the thing you passed to your function in the first place.

Even if you make the cast work using a cache of compiled expressions, one per type, which isn't hard to do, the output is still cast back to `object` by your very return type.

Comment: Your assumption about the `IEnumerable Cast(this IEnumerable items, Type type)` is wrong, of course we don't use that explicitly in our code as usual, we use that in context of `Reflection`, the input `items` and the returned `IEnumerable` are completely different in value (such as you can call `GetType` to know the difference). The `items` type is unable to be passed in some other method so we need a `Cast` here. Everything is done using Reflection (and `Expression`), no strongly type.

Comment: What makes you think that casting a reference type will change its `GetType` type? That's a virtual function, and casting a reference type won't change its virtual interface.

Comment: we do not cast the whole items, we cast on each item. So instead of `IEnumerable<object>` as the input, you have `IEnumerable<int>` as the output. That's just a simple example. Believe me, I do heavy reflection, without such kind of `Cast`, the code simply goes in runtime error. With `Cast`, it works. So what do you think about it? How do you pass in `IEnumerable<object>` in a method requiring an `IEnumerable<int>`? And we don't call that method as usual, we call that method using `Reflection`.

Comment: What in the world are you talking about, you're returning an untyped `IEnumerable` from your function, which is my entire point. Focus on just the types of the functions that you (I hope?) wrote.

Comment: if you use `Cast` normally, you just have an `IEnumerable` but when you use `Reflection` to consume that `IEnumerable`, the actual type will matter. In other words, you don't see the actual type of `IEnumerable` but the reflection code does see. So if it does not have a correct type, it will complain by throwing out an exception.

Comment: Casting doesn't change an object's type, only the typed interface through which you access its properties. Reflection can inspect an object's real type even through an `object` interface, sure, but you already had that. Casting it in your function then returning an `object` again (through `IEnumerable`) is worse than a no-op, it's a no-op that costs a lot of time.

Comment: casting in this case does not change item type BUT it changes the `IEnumerable` type. I'm trying to make you a simple demo with `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: check out this demo and you'll understand why such a `Cast` is needed when using reflection:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZky9r